# Microsoft Access query to duplicate ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, ms-access

Obviously there are a bunch of questions about ROW_NUMBER in MS Access and the usually response is that it does not exist but instead to use a COUNT(*) to create something similar. Unfortunately, doing so does not give me the results that I need.

My data looks like:

```
 RID | QID
 ---------
 1   | 1
 1   | 2
 1   | 3
 1   | 3
 2   | 1
 2   | 2
 2   | 2
```

What I am trying to get at is a unique count over RID and QID so that my query output looks like

```
 RID | QID | SeqID
 ------------------
 1   | 1   | 1
 1   | 2   | 1
 1   | 3   | 1
 1   | 3   | 2
 2   | 1   | 1
 2   | 2   | 1
 2   | 2   | 2
```

Using the COUNT(*) I get:

```
 RID | QID | SeqID
 ------------------
 1   | 1   | 1
 1   | 2   | 2
 1   | 3   | 3
 1   | 3   | 3
 2   | 1   | 1
 2   | 2   | 2
 2   | 2   | 2
```

My current query is:

```
 SELECT
      d.RID
      ,d.QID
      ,(SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            Data as d2
        WHERE
            d2.RID = d.RID
            AND d2.QID < d.QID) + 1 AS SeqID
 FROM 
      Data as d
 ORDER BY
      d.RID
      ,d.QID
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any other unique identifier in the table? or way of determining uniqueness such as values in combination of other columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Matt's comment implied, the only way to make this work is if you have some column in your table that can uniquely identify each row.

Based on what you have posted, you don't seem to have that. If that's the case, consider adding a new auto increment numeric column that can serve that purpose. Let's pretend that you call that new column `id`.

With that in place, the following query will work:

```
select t.rid, t.qid,
       (select count(*)
          from data t2
         where t2.rid = t.rid
           and t2.qid = t.qid
           and t2.id <= t.id) as SeqID
from data t
order by t.rid, t.qid
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdc404/4)

Comment: I do have a third column that I could use. Thanks!