# Difference of values in the same column ms access sql (mdb)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table which contains two column with values that are not unique, those values are generated automatically and I have no way to do anything about it, cannot edit the table, db nor make custom functions.

With that in mind I've solved this problem in sql server, but it contains some functions that does not exist in ms-access.

The columns are Volume and ComponentID, here is my code in sql:

```
with rows as (
                 select row_number() over (order by volume) as rownum, volume
                from   test where componentid = 'S3')
 
select top 10
       rowsMinusOne.volume, coalesce(rowsMinusOne.volume - rows.volume,0) as diff
from   rows as rowsMinusOne
                left outer join rows
                       on rows.rownum = rowsMinusOne.rownum - 1
```

Sample data:

```
58.29168 
70.57396
85.67902
97.04888
107.7026
108.2022
108.3975
108.5777
109
109.8944
```

Expected results:

| Volume | diff |
| --- | --- |
| 58.29168 | 0 |
| 70.57396 | 12.28228 |
| 85.67902 | 15.10506 |
| 97.04888 | 11.36986 |
| 107.7026 | 10.65368 |
| 108.2022 | 0.4996719 |
| 108.3975 | 0.1952896 |
| 108.5777 | 0.1801834 |
| 109 | 0.4223404 |
| 109.8944 | 0.89431 |

I have solved the part of the coalesce by replacing it with NZ, I have tryed to use the DCOUNT to solve the row_number ([How to show the record number in a MS Access report table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083240/how-to-show-the-record-number-in-a-ms-access-report-table/28086340#28086340)) but I reveive the error that it cannot find the function (I am reading the data by code, that is the only thing I can do).

I also tryed this but, as the answer says I need a column with a unique value which I do not have nor can create [Microsoft Access query to duplicate ROW_NUMBER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174944/microsoft-access-query-to-duplicate-row-number)

Comment: Mosy people here want _sample table data_, and the expected result, as formatted text - not images.

Comment: @jarrlh sorry let me edit my question.

Comment: Not seeing ComponentID in sample data. I presume the two fields together would not produce unique value.

Comment: You tested with SQLServer but data is not in SQLServer?

Comment: @june7 I do not use ComponenetID to show any data, it is used only to filter information and none of them produce an unique value.
I have tested with SQLServer but the data is in ms-access (mdb file), I am trying to do the same but not using the functions that are only available in SQLServer like ROW_Number and  COALEASE, for coalease I know the function equivalent, but for ROW_Number I have not found anything that would help me.

Comment: To confirm, ComponentID and Volume together would not produce a unique value? You show the Volume as increasing, so that is how data should be sorted? You do not show any duplicate volumes. Show sample raw data (both fields), not just desired result.

Comment: They would not produce an unique value, the database has over 40k rows and some of them contains volume 0 and same ComponentID

Comment: Would excluding the 0 volume records provide unique values?

Comment: Yes, that would produce unique values

Comment: Easiest approach is to build query that calculates difference, use that query as source for a report, use textbox RunningSum property to calculate sequence number.

Comment: I'm always baffled by this sort of question. You have solved the problem, why not use this solution? Export the data to SQL Server, run the query there, import the result back (if necessary). This is fast. Even if you get it to run, the simulated ROW_NUMBER with DCount would be terribly slow on 40k rows. Can't use code? Link the table from the mdb into a db of your own, where you can.

Comment: @Andre These kind of questions exist because of companies that tell you what you can do and what you cant do, for example it was not my election to have this machine outside a network and I definetly did not choose to develop the application with ms-access, I am not even allowed to use ms-access so I had to work somehow and imported the db into SQL to test things out, until I solved It and realize that I cant use these functions because ms-access does not support them.


Pd: Even if I was allowed to install sql in that machine (which im not) I really doubt it would run propertly.

Comment: Then you tell them that it's simply not possible with these limitations. If they want a solution they have to change them. (p.s. *I am not even allowed to use ms-access* -- what exactly are you supposed to do?)

Comment: What do you mean by "not even allowed to use ms-access" - aren't you using Access?

Comment: Since you are filtering by ComponentID, sample data should include that field.

Comment: @June7 I meant to say that I can't have ms-access installed on my PC, because I am doing my practices on the company , so I have to find a way to do it, the "them that it's simply not possible with these limitations" it's not an option for me, even if it works slow that's just fine.

Ps. Sorry about not adding data for ComponentID, I'll have it in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Table1.ComponentID, 
DCount("*","Table1","ComponentID = 'S3' AND Volume<" & [Volume])+1 AS Seq, Table1.Volume, 
Nz(Table1.Volume -
    (SELECT Top 1 Dup.Volume FROM Table1 AS Dup 
     WHERE Dup.ComponentID = Table1.ComponentID AND Dup.Volume<Table1.Volume 
     ORDER BY Volume DESC),0) AS Diff
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.ComponentID)="S3"))
ORDER BY Table1.Volume;
```

This will likely perform very slowly with large dataset.

Alternative solutions:

1. build query that calculates difference, use that query as source for a report, use textbox RunningSum property to calculate sequence number
2. VBA looping through recordset and saving results to a 'temp' table
3. export to Excel