# Combine sorted records in MS Access

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, join, merge

I have two tables in MS Access with the same number of records that I want to "merge" together based on the alphabetical sorting of a common column (col3 in example below). The values in col3 are not unique, and there are no columns or combination of columns in the tables that can be used as a composite key, so an inner join returns excess values. All I want to do is match up records row for row based on the sorted order of col3. Example:

**Table 1**

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A2 | A3 |
| B1 | B2 | B3 |
| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| C1 | C2 | C3 |

**Table 2**

| col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A3 | E1 | E2 |
| B3 | F1 | F2 |
| C3 | G1 | G2 |
| C3 | G1 | G2 |

**Output Table**

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A2 | A3 | E1 | E2 |
| B1 | B2 | B3 | F1 | F2 |
| C1 | C2 | C3 | G1 | G2 |
| C1 | C2 | C3 | G1 | G2 |

I have tried to add column to each table with unique values using autonumber, but run into the "File sharing lock count exceeded. Increase MaxLocksPerFile registry entry." error, and I don't have registry editing permissions.

I have also tried exporting each table to excel, sorting based on col3, then reimporting the combined table, but this is tedious and leads to errors when re-importing into access.

Comment: Are you saying there are 3 fields in each table and A1, A2, A3 is data? Show data in a formatted table structure. Here is a tool for that https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables. Could possibly use VBA to add row number that could be used to join records. Tables have same number of records? Or use Excel to generate row number. Why do you have Excel tag selected?

Comment: What is the sort order you mention? just the way the rows appear? there is no guarantee that they will be stored/retrieved in that order. You have to have some logic to order them by: alphabetically by Col1 or Col1,Col2,Col3, or add a new numeric column and assign numbers manually. Or take them out to a spreadsheet and assign numbers there, and copy into Access.

Comment: See updated details above.

Comment: You need a ROW_NUMBER, I think, to join on that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174944/microsoft-access-query-to-duplicate-row-number or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753368/row-number-in-access-select-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an *AutoNumber* field to (a copy of) each table.

This will be assigned values from 1 and up.

Then join in those two fields:

```sql
Select 
    T1.Field1, T1.Field2, T1.Field3, T2.Field1, T2.Field2, T2.Field3 
From 
    T1
Inner Join 
    T2 On T2.Id = T1.Id
```

**Addendum**:

As a table per definition has no ordering, you will then have to:

- create and use a select query for each table to specify the order
- create two new empty tables having an AutoNumber field in addition to the fields of the queries
- create an append query for each select query using this as source to append the records to the two new tables
- modify the query above to join not the source tables but the new tables

Comment: I run into the "File sharing lock count exceeded. Increase MaxLocksPerFile registry entry." error when I try to do this, and I don't have registry editing permissions. Also, there is no guarantee both tables will be sorted the same way when I add the AutoNumber field to each table, so the ordering will not match up on the join.

Comment: OK, that complicates it a bit. See extended answer, please.

Comment: What about just using two recordsets for reading source tables and a recordset to write destination table ?